# How to save a name as a variable when saving a Data frame file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, save

I have to save several files at a time.

It is saved as **.txt** using **.to_csv.**

The following method is used to save the **Data Frames** of position, energy, number, event, and height.

```
position.to_csv('/HDD1/abc_position.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
energy.to_csv('/HDD1/abc_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
number.to_csv('/HDD1/abc_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
event.to_csv('/HDD1/abc_event.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
height.to_csv('/HDD1/abc_height.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
```

Let's check the save file name above. They contain **'abc'**.
I want to replace 'abc' with the variable **'A = abc'** without having to write it down many times.

In other words, it should be as follows.

```
A = abc
postion.to_csv('/HDD1/A_position.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
energy.to_csv('/HDD1/A_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
number.to_csv('/HDD1/A_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
event.to_csv('/HDD1/A_event.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
height.to_csv('/HDD1/A_height.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
```

Is there a way to save files using variables as above?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for f-strings?

```
A = 'abc'
postion.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_position.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
energy.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
number.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
event.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_event.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
height.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_height.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

can use an f-string. Let

```
A = 'abc'

postion.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_position.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
energy.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_energy.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
number.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_number.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
event.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_event.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
height.to_csv(f'/HDD1/{A}_height.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
```

---

***EDIT***
Aditional (don't know if pythonic) you can create dictionary with all your dataFrames and call this a simplier way:

```
dataFrames = {'position':position,
              'energy':energy,
              'number':number,
              'event':event,
              'height':height 
             }

A = 'abc'
dir = '/HHD1'

for key,val in dataFrames.items():
    val.to_csv(f'{dir}/{a}_{key}.txt',index=False,sep=" ")
```

The last one liner is the same as:

```
[val.to_csv(f'{dir}/{a}_{key}.txt',index=False,sep=" ") for key, val in dataFrames.items()]
```

I think the first way is more pythonic, but not sure